# Image distorted on rotation

Tags: pytorch, torch, torchvision

I tried rotating image but the rotated images looks distorted. Why is the rotated image distorted?

```
import torchvision.transforms.functional as TF
image = TF.rotate(img, angle)
```

[image]

Comment: what value did you use for `rotate`? it might help to also post the original image by itself (or a link to it) so someone could try to reproduce themselves.